# Perforce will not delete files and folders from Depot

Tags: perforce, delete-file

I have a workspace that some files and folders were deleted offline.  The workspace shows them there on the depot side.  No matter what I do, I cannot get it to remove those files/folders.  When I select "Mark for Delete" is says "file(s) not in client view."  Well I KNOW that.  That's why I want to remove them from the Depot!

The option for "Reconcile Offline Work" is grayed out.  No idea why.

"Remove from Workspace" returns either "file(s) not in client view." or "no files updated" depending on its mood.

I have other folders in that area that I need to keep but I want to clean up the Depot so ONLY those folders are shown.

If I try "Get Latest Revision" with a force (I figured copy them back then delete while online), it says "11 Files Removed" but changes nothing.  I have Refreshed and exited and restarted.

I am using P4V (GUI version)

Answer (score 1):

Your description of the situation as having simply deleted the files offline is not accurate.  If the files are not in your client view, it means you have ALSO either:

1. modified your client view
2. switched client workspaces

Undo whichever of these you did, and then `Reconcile` will see the missing files and open them for delete.

Since they are not currently in your client view, there is no association between the deleted files in your workspace and the corresponding depot files.  Any time you want Perforce to do anything involving files in your workspace, the client view needs to specify how those files relate to the depot.

**(adding more to take into account the comment about the client spec being deleted, and apparently recreated with a different view, which is pretty hard to tell you how to recover from since I don't know anything about the before/after state other than that there are files... somewhere.  Unfortunately it's not possible to simply undo a client spec deletion, short of a checkpoint restore, since client specs aren't versioned objects.)**

If you deleted your client spec, records of what you previously had synced to your client are deleted along with them (next time just update the Root if your workspace moves), and so Reconcile won't work, even if you recreate the client with the same View.

To be able to delete the files from P4V, you'll need to sync them, but it sounds like you have the additional problem of having re-created your client spec with an incorrect View, so you can't even sync the files yet.  Here's what you'll need to do:

1. Add the depot path to your client view.
2. Sync the files to your workspace.
3. Mark for Delete.
4. Submit.

From the command line syncing is optional, so you could do these steps to delete your client (again), recreate it (with the wide-open default view this time), open the files for delete, and submit:

```
p4 client -d YOUR_CLIENT
p4 client -o | p4 client -i
p4 delete -v //depot/files/to/delete/...  
p4 submit
```

Comment: The original client drive had its root letter changed.  The workspace would not update to the new drive letter.  I deleted the old workspace and made a new one pointing at the correct drive letter (same workspace name as the old one).

There are files and folders listed on the Depot that are not on the client.  The file icons have an x in them.  Nothing I do will remove them from the list.  Doing a Reconcile at the root level only shows files that are on client that are not in depot (I do not want to move these over).  It does NOT show any on the Depot side that are not on the client side.

Comment: This is a pretty basic configuration problem (again, it's all to do with how your client view is set up) but I can't tell you the specific things to change if I can't see the specifics of your configuration. Doing a back and forth on SO comment threads is hard, so I recommend posting on forums.perforce.com (I help people debug stuff like this there pretty routinely).  Include a screenshot of P4V and your current client view and it'll be an easy fix.

Comment: tl;dr: when you deleted and recreated your client you didn't carry the view over from the old client.  If you don't have a copy of the old client the easiest fix is for someone to just look at what you've got and tell you what it looks like it SHOULD be.  :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a spec depot, you may be able to use this to restore your workspace to a point before the view was changed.

More information about working with the spec depot is here:
  http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB/2445

Answer (score 0):

Perforce doesn't recognize the offline deleted files,  You have to get latest revision first with 'Fore Operation' Checked.
Now you will see all your deleted files in your depot.
If you still don't see your delete files in depot, then take a backup of the entire folder. Now delete the folder, and do a getlatest with 'Fore Operation' Checked.
Now you will for sure see the deleted files also under the depot.
Now you should do 'Mark for Delete' for the file u wish to delete from depot.